# How to I achieve nesting for objects having ParentKey?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects with Name, Key in all objects and ParentKey in some of the objects.

I want to group objects by unique 'Key' excluding those which have 'ParentKey'. The objects having ParentKey should be nested as reflected in required ans.

Initial Input :-

```js
const arr = [
    {
        Name: 'Manage Leads',
        Key: 'Manage Leads',
    },
    {
        Name: 'Dashboard',
        Key: 'Dashboard',
    },
    {
        Name: 'Smart Views',
        Key: 'Smart Views',
    },
    {
        Name: 'Lead Details',
        Key: 'Lead Details',
    },
    {
        Name: 'Opportunity Details',
        Key: 'Opportunity Details',
    },
    {
        Name: 'Header',
        Key: 'Header',
    },
    {
        Name: 'Settings',
        Key: 'Settings',
    },
    {
        Name: 'Test 1',
        Key: 'Test1Key',
    },
    {
        Name: 'Test 1.1',
        Key: 'Test1.1Key',
        ParentKey: 'Test1',
    },
    {
        Name: 'Test 1.2',
        Key: 'Test1.2Key',
        ParentKey: 'Test1',
    },
    {
        Name: 'Test 1.1.1',
        Key: 'Test1.1.1Key',
        ParentKey: 'Test 1.1',
    },
    {
        Name: 'Test 1.1.2',
        Key: 'Test1.1.2Key',
        ParentKey: 'Test 1.1',
    },
    {
        Name: 'Test 1.2.1',
        Key: 'Test1.2.1Key',
        ParentKey: 'Test 1.2',
    },
];
```

Required Output :-

```js
 [
    {
        groupName: 'Manage Leads',
        actionsArr: [{ Name: 'Manage Leads', Key: 'Manage Leads' }],
    },
    {
        groupName: 'Dashboard',
        actionsArr: [{ Name: 'Dashboard', Key: 'Dashboard' }],
    },
    {
        groupName: 'Smart Views',
        actionsArr: [{ Name: 'Smart Views', Key: 'Smart Views' }],
    },
    {
        groupName: 'Lead Details',
        actionsArr: [{ Name: 'Lead Details', Key: 'Lead Details' }],
    },
    {
        groupName: 'Opportunity Details',
        actionsArr: [
            {
                Name: 'Opportunity Details',
                Key: 'Opportunity Details',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        groupName: 'Header',
        actionsArr: [{ Name: 'Header', Key: 'Header' }],
    },
    {
        groupName: 'Settings',
        actionsArr: [{ Name: 'Settings', Key: 'Settings' }],
    },
    {
        groupName: 'Test1Key',
        actionsArr: [
            {
                Name: 'Test 1',
                Key: 'Test1Key',
                subActions: [
                    {
                        Name: 'Test 1.1',
                        Key: 'Test1.1',
                        ParentKey: 'Test1Key',
                        subActions: [
                            {
                                Name: 'Test 1.1.1',
                                Key: 'Test1.1.1Key',
                                ParentKey: 'Test 1.1',
                            },
                            {
                                Name: 'Test 1.1.2',
                                Key: 'Test1.1.2Key',
                                ParentKey: 'Test 1.1',
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                    {
                        Name: 'Test 1.2',
                        Key: 'Test1.2',
                        ParentKey: 'Test1Key',
                        subActions: [
                            {
                                Name: 'Test 1.2.1',
                                Key: 'Test1.2.1Key',
                                ParentKey: 'Test 1.2',
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

I was able to group by unique Key with the follwoing code but i'm not able to nest the objects which have ParentKey.

```
const groupNames = [...new Set(actions.map((item) => item.GroupKey))];
const actionsList = groupNames.map((groupName) => {
const actionsArr = actions.filter((act) => act.GroupKey === groupName);
return { label: groupName, value: actionsArr }});
```

Comment: Is the given array always ordered such that the nested objects come after their parents?

Answer (score 1):

I found some inconsistencies between Key and ParentKey for the given data.
I have fixed the inconsistencies in the input data, and I would be using the same.

Here is the solution that worked for me.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    Name: "Manage Leads",
    Key: "Manage Leads",
  },
  {
    Name: "Dashboard",
    Key: "Dashboard",
  },
  {
    Name: "Smart Views",
    Key: "Smart Views",
  },
  {
    Name: "Lead Details",
    Key: "Lead Details",
  },
  {
    Name: "Opportunity Details",
    Key: "Opportunity Details",
  },
  {
    Name: "Header",
    Key: "Header",
  },
  {
    Name: "Settings",
    Key: "Settings",
  },
  {
    Name: "Test 1",
    Key: "Test1Key",
  },
  {
    Name: "Test 1.1",
    Key: "Test1.1Key",
    ParentKey: "Test 1",
  },
  {
    Name: "Test 1.2",
    Key: "Test1.2Key",
    ParentKey: "Test 1",
  },
  {
    Name: "Test 1.1.1",
    Key: "Test1.1.1Key",
    ParentKey: "Test 1.1",
  },
  {
    Name: "Test 1.1.2",
    Key: "Test1.1.2Key",
    ParentKey: "Test 1.1",
  },
  {
    Name: "Test 1.2.1",
    Key: "Test1.2.1Key",
    ParentKey: "Test 1.2",
  },
];

//recursively look for the child and append child to parent
const appendChild = (parent, arr) => {
  for (let index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
    const childElement = arr[index];

    if (childElement.ParentKey == parent.Name) {
      appendChild(childElement, arr);

      if (parent.subActions) {
        parent.subActions.push(childElement);
      } else {
        parent.subActions = [childElement];
      }

      //remove the child from that list and match the index
      arr.splice(index, 1);
      index--;
    }
  }
};

//convert data into a parent-child hierarchy
const convert = (arr) => {
  for (const parent of arr) {
    appendChild(parent, arr);
  }
  
  //filter out items which has been already added as child/subActions
  return arr.filter((x) => !Boolean(x.ParentKey));
};

const groupBy = (items, callback) => {
  const groupedData = items.reduce(
    (acc, value, index) => (
      (acc[callback(value, index, items)] ||= []).push(value), acc
    ),
    {}
  );

//convert grouped data as the required output
  return Object.entries(groupedData).map(([key, value]) => ({
    groupName: key,
    actionsArr: value,
  }));
};

const data = groupBy(convert(arr), (x) => x.Name);

console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "groupName": "Manage Leads",
    "actionsArr": [
      {
        "Name": "Manage Leads",
        "Key": "Manage Leads"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "groupName": "Dashboard",
    "actionsArr": [
      {
        "Name": "Dashboard",
        "Key": "Dashboard"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "groupName": "Smart Views",
    "actionsArr": [
      {
        "Name": "Smart Views",
        "Key": "Smart Views"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "groupName": "Lead Details",
    "actionsArr": [
      {
        "Name": "Lead Details",
        "Key": "Lead Details"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "groupName": "Opportunity Details",
    "actionsArr": [
      {
        "Name": "Opportunity Details",
        "Key": "Opportunity Details"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "groupName": "Header",
    "actionsArr": [
      {
        "Name": "Header",
        "Key": "Header"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "groupName": "Settings",
    "actionsArr": [
      {
        "Name": "Settings",
        "Key": "Settings"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "groupName": "Test 1",
    "actionsArr": [
      {
        "Name": "Test 1",
        "Key": "Test1Key",
        "subActions": [
          {
            "Name": "Test 1.1",
            "Key": "Test1.1Key",
            "ParentKey": "Test 1",
            "subActions": [
              {
                "Name": "Test 1.1.1",
                "Key": "Test1.1.1Key",
                "ParentKey": "Test 1.1"
              },
              {
                "Name": "Test 1.1.2",
                "Key": "Test1.1.2Key",
                "ParentKey": "Test 1.1"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Name": "Test 1.2",
            "Key": "Test1.2Key",
            "ParentKey": "Test 1",
            "subActions": [
              {
                "Name": "Test 1.2.1",
                "Key": "Test1.2.1Key",
                "ParentKey": "Test 1.2"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```